# In Excel VBA, the volatile Offset function is very slow. What is a alternative?

Tags: performance, excel, vba, offset

I'm having a performance issue in my Excel macro. One particular piece of code runs really slow. I think the reason is the `Offset` function. I've found online that it is a volatile function which recalculates a lot.
The strange thing is that I use it as a VBA-function, so I can't figure out how it would affect performance as it never *needs* to be recalculated.

This is how I use the offset function:

```
For i=0 To 10
 For P=0 To 3
  For T=0 To 3
    Range("C9").Offset(6 * i + T, P).Value = effect(i,P,T)
  Next
 Next
Next
```

Is there a faster (nonvolatile?) alternative?

Comment: I believe the *Excel* `OFFSET()` function is volatile -- not the VBA `.Offset` property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `Cells(row,column).Value = ...`

Obviously you will need to adjust `row` and `column` to account for your starting position of C9 (9,3)

Also are you sure that the function `effect()` isn't the bottleneck?

UPDATE:

Also have you tried

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ....Your Code....
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: wow, huge difference. Just went from 30 seconds to 3 seconds by just adding your 2 lines of code. Thanks!

Comment: Dude, the impact of these lines is _over 9000!_ Together with Application.CalculateFull I managed to speed up **all** my calculations about 7 times

Comment: Just make sure that you don't have code that may error out and leave Application.CalculationManual switched on - it really p****s people off!